# Can we really move disks around a compact surface like this?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, polytopes, low-dimensional-topology

On page 4 of [this](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4306&context=etd) Master's thesis, we have:

> **Lemma 2.2.** Let $F$ be a compact surface, let $D_1, \ldots , D_k$ be a collection of pairwise-disjoint disks embedded in $F$ and let $D_1', \ldots , D_k'$ be a second collection of disjoint embedded disks. There is a homeomorpism $\varphi : F \rightarrow F$, isotopic to the identity, such that $\varphi$ sends each disk $D_i$ onto the disk $D_i'.$

The proof is just a reference to C. P. Rourke and B. J. Sanderson's 1972 edition of Introduction to piecewise-linear topology. I'm looking at the Springer Study edition of this same book, but the one I'm looking at was published in 1982. In any event, there's no hint of this theorem being in there. There's something called the "Disc Theorem" on page 44 that seems vaguely related, but only works for discs in the interior of the manifold and which therefore isn't directly applicable.

> **Question.** What's going on here? Is this lemma legitimate, and if so, how do we know it's true?

Comment: This is the sort of thing that's obviously true, but proving it is so tedious that authors resort to hand-waving.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is it though? The case where some $D_i$ touches the boundary of $F$ and $D_i'$ doesn't seems not-obvious to me.

Comment: Are they *open* disks? and are you sure F is supposed to have nonempty boundary? it seems unclear just from glancing at the thesis.

Comment: i mean clearly (as Fimpellizieri says) youre never going to get an ambient homeomorphism throwing a closed ball in the interior onto a closed ball intersecting the boundary. so my guess is one of those two things is whats going on. i.e. the disks are in the interior.

Comment: and if thats the case, I'd recommend Kosinksi's proof of the disk theorem (in Differential Manifolds)-- Thm 3.5 and its corollary.  Basically it follows from a more general fact that if you have two compact submanifolds and an isotopy between them, then you can extend the isotopy to (imbeddings of) their normal bundles.